# text-indent CSS property is not hiding text on bootstrap slider

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Twitter Boostrap carousel to display 3 seperate sliders, each of which has a background image, and a "more" button which I display as an image:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image: url('/content/images/slider/header-1.jpg');">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="span6">
                        @Html.ActionLink("More", "MoreInfo1", null, new { @class = "morebutton" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image: url('/content/images/slider/header-1.jpg');">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="span6">
                        @Html.ActionLink("More", "MoreInfo2", null, new { @class = "morebutton" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="fill" style="background-image: url('/content/images/slider/header-1.jpg');">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="span6">
                        @Html.ActionLink("More", "MoreInfo3", null, new { @class = "morebutton" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The class that shows the more button has the following CSS properties:

```
a.morebutton
{
    background: url(/Content/Images/more.png) no-repeat top left;
     display: block;
     width: 80px;
     height: 25px;
     margin-top:15px;
     text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
}
```

Unfortunately while the text-indent works on the first slider, the text is overlaid over the image on the 2nd and 3rd. Any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: are you floating the buttons as I don't think text-indent works on floated elements

Comment: No I'm not floating - and the text-indent works on the first item in the carousel, just not the others

Comment: Are you able to set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that will replicate the error as the above code should work fine

Comment: I ended up using a pure css button as opposed to an image.